# How to differentiate AJAX calls made from my application (client) vs elsewhere?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, encryption, cryptojs

I have a back end running node. I have a front end application that will make AJAX requests to the back end, such as a post request to submit a contact form (not an actual form, but a series of inputs that the post request aggregates user input from to send a payload). Is there a way to differentiate between the various AJAX calls that my application is making vs say a developer in the console who would try and make those calls manually?

My thought was that my application would send some sort of payload with each type of request so that the server could check for said payload and know it was the app making the call. Problem is, I'm not sure how the app itself can both generate that payload on the fly (i.e. not me sending a string of data that's hard-coded in the JS) while keeping it secret. I looked into crypto-js, but it seems that I would have to store the key in my code somewhere which would just defeat the purpose. I hope I just said all that correctly.

Comment: "Is there a way to differentiate" --- nope.

Comment: So you want to let the user user your app but not let him use your API? Using one or the other should not make a difference.

Comment: @Bergi I want the app to be able to request things from my api that someone in the console via AJAX can not. In essence, I want the app to be the gateway to the api.

Comment: @TheQodesmith: No, that's not possible. The API is the gateway.